# Word Wrapping and Boxing

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

This was an experiment to take any text and wrap it to a given number of columns. It also wraps
the text in just one box, lets you box multiple blocks of text, and also lets you limit the number
of boxes per line. The main paragraph tested was one that I found on Yahoo that I thought was
really fun to use as a test. Would you be willing to look at my code for clarity and the algorithm
for efficiency?

### WordWrap.java

```
package wordwrap;

public class WordWrap {
    private static String wordWrap(String text, int width, String delim) {
        String out = "";
        String[] words;
        int currentWidth = 0;

        //Parse out tabs and new lines
        text = text.replaceAll("[\t\n]", " ");
        words = text.split(delim);

        //Rewrap to new width
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.length() >= width) {
                //If it's not the first word, put it on a new line
                if (!out.isEmpty()) {
                    out += "\n";
                }
                out += word + " ";
                currentWidth = word.length();
            }
            else if ((currentWidth + word.length()) <= width) {
                out += word + " ";
                currentWidth += word.length() + 1;
            } else {
                out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
                out += "\n" + word + " ";
                currentWidth = word.length() + 1;
            }
        }

        return out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
    }

    public static String wordWrap(String text, int width) {
        return wordWrap(text, width, " ");
    }

    public static String drawBox(String text, int width) {
        String out;
        String border;
        String[] lines;

        border = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < (width - 2); i++) {
            border += "-";
        }
        border += " \n";

        out = border;

        if (width < 5) {
            width = 5;
        }
        width -= 4;
        lines = wordWrap(text, width).split("\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            out += String.format("| %-" + width + "s |\n", line);
        }

        out += border;

        return out;
    }

    public static String drawBoxes(String[] messages, int width) {
        String out = "";
        String[] boxes = new String[messages.length];
        String[][] lines;   //String[box's full string][array of box's string split at new line]
        int maxBoxLines = 0;

        if (messages.length == 1) {
            out = drawBox(messages[0], width);
        }
        else {
            width = width / messages.length - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                boxes[i] = drawBox(messages[i], width);
            }

            for (String box : boxes) {
                int boxLines = box.split("\n").length;
                if (boxLines > maxBoxLines) {
                    maxBoxLines = boxLines;
                }
            }
            lines = new String[boxes.length][maxBoxLines];

            for (int b = 0; b < boxes.length; b++) {
                lines[b] = boxes[b].split("\n");
            }

            for (int l = 0; l < maxBoxLines; l++) {
                String currentLine = "";
                for (int b = 0; b < boxes.length; b++) {
                    if (l >= lines[b].length) {
                        currentLine += String.format("%" + width + "s ", "");
                    }
                    else {
                        currentLine += lines[b][l] + " ";
                    }
                }
                out += currentLine.substring(0, currentLine.length() - 1) + "\n";
            }
        }

        return out;
    }

    public static String drawBoxes(String[] messages, int width, int boxesWide) {
        String out = "";

        if (messages.length <= boxesWide) {
            out = WordWrap.drawBoxes(messages, width);
        }
        else {
            int currentBox = 0;
            String[] currentMessages;

            while (currentBox < messages.length) {
                if (boxesWide > messages.length - currentBox) {
                    boxesWide = messages.length - currentBox;
                }

                currentMessages = new String[boxesWide];

                for (int i = 0; i < boxesWide; i++) {
                    currentMessages[i] = messages[currentBox];
                    currentBox++;
                }

                out += WordWrap.drawBoxes(currentMessages, width) + "\n";
            }
        }

        return out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

### WordWrapTest.java

```
package wordwrap;

import static wordwrap.WordWrap.*;

public class WordWrapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int WIDTH = 100;

        final String sample = "Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a journey. They were looking "
                + "for the great treasure of Ecrapolis. On their way\nthey got lost and camped "
                + "inside a giant elephant. they awoke the next morning to find that the elephant "
                + "had walked\nthem to Los Angeles. Being from an underground secret city, Jerry "
                + "and the midgets had no idea what to think of this.\nThey all went out exploring "
                + "the city, and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. Jerry tried surfing and "
                + "was thrown off\nhis board into the sand, mouth-first. He proceeded to munch the "
                + "sand down, saying it as the best food he'd had in\nages. Suddenly while digging "
                + "through this delectable muck, he hit something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST!\n"
                + "He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets crowded around him. Unable to fathom what "
                + "was inside he tore it open. Inside\nwas a note, \"Ha Ha! There's no real "
                + "treasure You retarded egg goblin!!\" With that note, Jerry and the midgets "
                + "turned\npurple and floated into outer space, doomed to wander the universe.";
        final String sample2 = "Blah blah blah blah blah\n";

        System.out.println("Raw Sample:\n" + sample + "\n");

        System.out.println("Wrapped sample:\n" + wordWrap(sample, WIDTH) + "\n");

        System.out.println("Boxed sample:\n" + drawBox(sample, WIDTH));

        String[] samples = { sample2, sample };
        System.out.println("Boxed samples:\n" + drawBoxes(samples, WIDTH));

        String[] samples2 = { sample, sample2, sample };
        System.out.println("Boxed samples3:\n" + drawBoxes(samples2, WIDTH));

        String[] samples3 = { sample, sample2, sample2, sample };
        System.out.println("Boxed samples3:\n" + drawBoxes(samples3, WIDTH));

        String[] samples4 = { sample, sample2, sample, sample2, sample, };
        System.out.println("Boxed samples4:\n" + drawBoxes(samples4, WIDTH, 3));
    }
}
```

### Test Output

```
Raw Sample:
Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a journey. They were looking for the great treasure of Ecrapolis. On their way
they got lost and camped inside a giant elephant. they awoke the next morning to find that the elephant had walked
them to Los Angeles. Being from an underground secret city, Jerry and the midgets had no idea what to think of this.
They all went out exploring the city, and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. Jerry tried surfing and was thrown off
his board into the sand, mouth-first. He proceeded to munch the sand down, saying it as the best food he'd had in
ages. Suddenly while digging through this delectable muck, he hit something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST!
He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets crowded around him. Unable to fathom what was inside he tore it open. Inside
was a note, "Ha Ha! There's no real treasure You retarded egg goblin!!" With that note, Jerry and the midgets turned
purple and floated into outer space, doomed to wander the universe.

Wrapped sample:
Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a journey. They were looking for the great treasure of
Ecrapolis. On their way they got lost and camped inside a giant elephant. they awoke the next
morning to find that the elephant had walked them to Los Angeles. Being from an underground secret
city, Jerry and the midgets had no idea what to think of this. They all went out exploring the city,
and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. Jerry tried surfing and was thrown off his board into
the sand, mouth-first. He proceeded to munch the sand down, saying it as the best food he'd had in
ages. Suddenly while digging through this delectable muck, he hit something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE
CHEST! He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets crowded around him. Unable to fathom what was inside he
tore it open. Inside was a note, "Ha Ha! There's no real treasure You retarded egg goblin!!" With
that note, Jerry and the midgets turned purple and floated into outer space, doomed to wander the
universe.

Boxed sample:
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a journey. They were looking for the great treasure of      |
| Ecrapolis. On their way they got lost and camped inside a giant elephant. they awoke the next    |
| morning to find that the elephant had walked them to Los Angeles. Being from an underground      |
| secret city, Jerry and the midgets had no idea what to think of this. They all went out          |
| exploring the city, and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. Jerry tried surfing and was    |
| thrown off his board into the sand, mouth-first. He proceeded to munch the sand down, saying it  |
| as the best food he'd had in ages. Suddenly while digging through this delectable muck, he hit   |
| something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST! He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets crowded around    |
| him. Unable to fathom what was inside he tore it open. Inside was a note, "Ha Ha! There's no     |
| real treasure You retarded egg goblin!!" With that note, Jerry and the midgets turned purple and |
| floated into outer space, doomed to wander the universe.                                         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Boxed samples:
 -----------------------------------------------   ----------------------------------------------- 
| Blah blah blah blah blah                      | | Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a        |
 -----------------------------------------------  | journey. They were looking for the great      |
                                                  | treasure of Ecrapolis. On their way they got  |
                                                  | lost and camped inside a giant elephant. they |
                                                  | awoke the next morning to find that the       |
                                                  | elephant had walked them to Los Angeles.      |
                                                  | Being from an underground secret city, Jerry  |
                                                  | and the midgets had no idea what to think of  |
                                                  | this. They all went out exploring the city,   |
                                                  | and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |
                                                  | Jerry tried surfing and was thrown off his    |
                                                  | board into the sand, mouth-first. He          |
                                                  | proceeded to munch the sand down, saying it   |
                                                  | as the best food he'd had in ages. Suddenly   |
                                                  | while digging through this delectable muck,   |
                                                  | he hit something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE      |
                                                  | CHEST! He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets  |
                                                  | crowded around him. Unable to fathom what was |
                                                  | inside he tore it open. Inside was a note,    |
                                                  | "Ha Ha! There's no real treasure You retarded |
                                                  | egg goblin!!" With that note, Jerry and the   |
                                                  | midgets turned purple and floated into outer  |
                                                  | space, doomed to wander the universe.         |
                                                   ----------------------------------------------- 

Boxed samples3:
 ------------------------------   ------------------------------   ------------------------------ 
| Once Jerry and 16 midgets    | | Blah blah blah blah blah     | | Once Jerry and 16 midgets    |
| set off on a journey. They   |  ------------------------------  | set off on a journey. They   |
| were looking for the great   |                                  | were looking for the great   |
| treasure of Ecrapolis. On    |                                  | treasure of Ecrapolis. On    |
| their way they got lost and  |                                  | their way they got lost and  |
| camped inside a giant        |                                  | camped inside a giant        |
| elephant. they awoke the     |                                  | elephant. they awoke the     |
| next morning to find that    |                                  | next morning to find that    |
| the elephant had walked them |                                  | the elephant had walked them |
| to Los Angeles. Being from   |                                  | to Los Angeles. Being from   |
| an underground secret city,  |                                  | an underground secret city,  |
| Jerry and the midgets had no |                                  | Jerry and the midgets had no |
| idea what to think of this.  |                                  | idea what to think of this.  |
| They all went out exploring  |                                  | They all went out exploring  |
| the city, and got into all   |                                  | the city, and got into all   |
| sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |                                  | sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |
| Jerry tried surfing and was  |                                  | Jerry tried surfing and was  |
| thrown off his board into    |                                  | thrown off his board into    |
| the sand, mouth-first. He    |                                  | the sand, mouth-first. He    |
| proceeded to munch the sand  |                                  | proceeded to munch the sand  |
| down, saying it as the best  |                                  | down, saying it as the best  |
| food he'd had in ages.       |                                  | food he'd had in ages.       |
| Suddenly while digging       |                                  | Suddenly while digging       |
| through this delectable      |                                  | through this delectable      |
| muck, he hit something hard. |                                  | muck, he hit something hard. |
| IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST! He  |                                  | IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST! He  |
| opened it slowly as the 16   |                                  | opened it slowly as the 16   |
| midgets crowded around him.  |                                  | midgets crowded around him.  |
| Unable to fathom what was    |                                  | Unable to fathom what was    |
| inside he tore it open.      |                                  | inside he tore it open.      |
| Inside was a note, "Ha Ha!   |                                  | Inside was a note, "Ha Ha!   |
| There's no real treasure You |                                  | There's no real treasure You |
| retarded egg goblin!!" With  |                                  | retarded egg goblin!!" With  |
| that note, Jerry and the     |                                  | that note, Jerry and the     |
| midgets turned purple and    |                                  | midgets turned purple and    |
| floated into outer space,    |                                  | floated into outer space,    |
| doomed to wander the         |                                  | doomed to wander the         |
| universe.                    |                                  | universe.                    |
 ------------------------------                                    ------------------------------ 

Boxed samples3:
 ----------------------   ----------------------   ----------------------   ---------------------- 
| Once Jerry and 16    | | Blah blah blah blah  | | Blah blah blah blah  | | Once Jerry and 16    |
| midgets set off on a | | blah                 | | blah                 | | midgets set off on a |
| journey. They were   |  ----------------------   ----------------------  | journey. They were   |
| looking for the      |                                                   | looking for the      |
| great treasure of    |                                                   | great treasure of    |
| Ecrapolis. On their  |                                                   | Ecrapolis. On their  |
| way they got lost    |                                                   | way they got lost    |
| and camped inside a  |                                                   | and camped inside a  |
| giant elephant. they |                                                   | giant elephant. they |
| awoke the next       |                                                   | awoke the next       |
| morning to find that |                                                   | morning to find that |
| the elephant had     |                                                   | the elephant had     |
| walked them to Los   |                                                   | walked them to Los   |
| Angeles. Being from  |                                                   | Angeles. Being from  |
| an underground       |                                                   | an underground       |
| secret city, Jerry   |                                                   | secret city, Jerry   |
| and the midgets had  |                                                   | and the midgets had  |
| no idea what to      |                                                   | no idea what to      |
| think of this. They  |                                                   | think of this. They  |
| all went out         |                                                   | all went out         |
| exploring the city,  |                                                   | exploring the city,  |
| and got into all     |                                                   | and got into all     |
| sorts of crazy-asss  |                                                   | sorts of crazy-asss  |
| trouble. Jerry tried |                                                   | trouble. Jerry tried |
| surfing and was      |                                                   | surfing and was      |
| thrown off his board |                                                   | thrown off his board |
| into the sand,       |                                                   | into the sand,       |
| mouth-first. He      |                                                   | mouth-first. He      |
| proceeded to munch   |                                                   | proceeded to munch   |
| the sand down,       |                                                   | the sand down,       |
| saying it as the     |                                                   | saying it as the     |
| best food he'd had   |                                                   | best food he'd had   |
| in ages. Suddenly    |                                                   | in ages. Suddenly    |
| while digging        |                                                   | while digging        |
| through this         |                                                   | through this         |
| delectable muck, he  |                                                   | delectable muck, he  |
| hit something hard.  |                                                   | hit something hard.  |
| IT WAS A TREASURE    |                                                   | IT WAS A TREASURE    |
| CHEST! He opened it  |                                                   | CHEST! He opened it  |
| slowly as the 16     |                                                   | slowly as the 16     |
| midgets crowded      |                                                   | midgets crowded      |
| around him. Unable   |                                                   | around him. Unable   |
| to fathom what was   |                                                   | to fathom what was   |
| inside he tore it    |                                                   | inside he tore it    |
| open. Inside was a   |                                                   | open. Inside was a   |
| note, "Ha Ha!        |                                                   | note, "Ha Ha!        |
| There's no real      |                                                   | There's no real      |
| treasure You         |                                                   | treasure You         |
| retarded egg         |                                                   | retarded egg         |
| goblin!!" With that  |                                                   | goblin!!" With that  |
| note, Jerry and the  |                                                   | note, Jerry and the  |
| midgets turned       |                                                   | midgets turned       |
| purple and floated   |                                                   | purple and floated   |
| into outer space,    |                                                   | into outer space,    |
| doomed to wander the |                                                   | doomed to wander the |
| universe.            |                                                   | universe.            |
 ----------------------                                                     ---------------------- 

Boxed samples4:
 ------------------------------   ------------------------------   ------------------------------ 
| Once Jerry and 16 midgets    | | Blah blah blah blah blah     | | Once Jerry and 16 midgets    |
| set off on a journey. They   |  ------------------------------  | set off on a journey. They   |
| were looking for the great   |                                  | were looking for the great   |
| treasure of Ecrapolis. On    |                                  | treasure of Ecrapolis. On    |
| their way they got lost and  |                                  | their way they got lost and  |
| camped inside a giant        |                                  | camped inside a giant        |
| elephant. they awoke the     |                                  | elephant. they awoke the     |
| next morning to find that    |                                  | next morning to find that    |
| the elephant had walked them |                                  | the elephant had walked them |
| to Los Angeles. Being from   |                                  | to Los Angeles. Being from   |
| an underground secret city,  |                                  | an underground secret city,  |
| Jerry and the midgets had no |                                  | Jerry and the midgets had no |
| idea what to think of this.  |                                  | idea what to think of this.  |
| They all went out exploring  |                                  | They all went out exploring  |
| the city, and got into all   |                                  | the city, and got into all   |
| sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |                                  | sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |
| Jerry tried surfing and was  |                                  | Jerry tried surfing and was  |
| thrown off his board into    |                                  | thrown off his board into    |
| the sand, mouth-first. He    |                                  | the sand, mouth-first. He    |
| proceeded to munch the sand  |                                  | proceeded to munch the sand  |
| down, saying it as the best  |                                  | down, saying it as the best  |
| food he'd had in ages.       |                                  | food he'd had in ages.       |
| Suddenly while digging       |                                  | Suddenly while digging       |
| through this delectable      |                                  | through this delectable      |
| muck, he hit something hard. |                                  | muck, he hit something hard. |
| IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST! He  |                                  | IT WAS A TREASURE CHEST! He  |
| opened it slowly as the 16   |                                  | opened it slowly as the 16   |
| midgets crowded around him.  |                                  | midgets crowded around him.  |
| Unable to fathom what was    |                                  | Unable to fathom what was    |
| inside he tore it open.      |                                  | inside he tore it open.      |
| Inside was a note, "Ha Ha!   |                                  | Inside was a note, "Ha Ha!   |
| There's no real treasure You |                                  | There's no real treasure You |
| retarded egg goblin!!" With  |                                  | retarded egg goblin!!" With  |
| that note, Jerry and the     |                                  | that note, Jerry and the     |
| midgets turned purple and    |                                  | midgets turned purple and    |
| floated into outer space,    |                                  | floated into outer space,    |
| doomed to wander the         |                                  | doomed to wander the         |
| universe.                    |                                  | universe.                    |
 ------------------------------                                    ------------------------------ 

 -----------------------------------------------   ----------------------------------------------- 
| Blah blah blah blah blah                      | | Once Jerry and 16 midgets set off on a        |
 -----------------------------------------------  | journey. They were looking for the great      |
                                                  | treasure of Ecrapolis. On their way they got  |
                                                  | lost and camped inside a giant elephant. they |
                                                  | awoke the next morning to find that the       |
                                                  | elephant had walked them to Los Angeles.      |
                                                  | Being from an underground secret city, Jerry  |
                                                  | and the midgets had no idea what to think of  |
                                                  | this. They all went out exploring the city,   |
                                                  | and got into all sorts of crazy-asss trouble. |
                                                  | Jerry tried surfing and was thrown off his    |
                                                  | board into the sand, mouth-first. He          |
                                                  | proceeded to munch the sand down, saying it   |
                                                  | as the best food he'd had in ages. Suddenly   |
                                                  | while digging through this delectable muck,   |
                                                  | he hit something hard. IT WAS A TREASURE      |
                                                  | CHEST! He opened it slowly as the 16 midgets  |
                                                  | crowded around him. Unable to fathom what was |
                                                  | inside he tore it open. Inside was a note,    |
                                                  | "Ha Ha! There's no real treasure You retarded |
                                                  | egg goblin!!" With that note, Jerry and the   |
                                                  | midgets turned purple and floated into outer  |
                                                  | space, doomed to wander the universe.         |
                                                   -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### String concatenation

String concatenation using `+=` is inefficient. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

#### Preparation before splitting

The replacement before splitting could be improved here:

```
    //Parse out tabs and new lines
    text = text.replaceAll("[\t\n]", " ");
    words = text.split(delim);
```

Multiple consecutive whitespace characters will result in multiple consecutive space characters. And since the default delimiter is space, the words array may contain empty elements. I recommend to adjust the replacement pattern for better results:

```
    text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

#### Declare variables right before you need them

In many places of there code you declare variables at the top of a function, even if they won't be used by all execution branches. This is not recommended. It's best to declare variables right before you need them. This is to minimize the *live time*, which is a window of vulnerability when the variable can be misused, leading to bugs.

#### Unit testing

Instead of printing formatted text to standard output, this kind of functionality really begs for unit testing, where you assert the expected outputs, which automated the verification step for you, so that you don't have to re-read and verify with your eyes.